# Initialize word document content type properties using Javascript

Tags: javascript, document, word

I'm trying to create a new word document from a template using the following javascript code :

```
var word = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
var doc = word.Documents.Add("/server/docLib/ContentType/template.dotx");
```

before i display the word application, i want to initialize some content types properties :

```
doc.ContentTypeProperties.GetItemByInternalName("field1_internalName").Value = "MyValue"
```

The previous code works fine. But when I try to set a property of type Lookup, an exception is raised with no error description.

To see what was wrong, i used the following code to open an existing document with all properties filled.

```
var word = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
var doc = word.Documents.Open("/server/docLib/doc1.docx");
var ct = doc.ContentTypeProperties;
var lookupprop = ct.GetItemByInternalName("field1_internalName");
```

After debugging, I found that lookupprop is an object of type MetaProperty and contains somme fields like Type, ID... etc. and **Value** of type **Variant**. when i tried to acces the value, the same exception was raised.

My question is : Is it possible to set a lookup properties like this? and if yes how?

Answer (score 1):

Lookup columns are special and require special interaction, please read this excerpt from MSDN:

```
    function addNewSale(employeeId, salesachieved, customer, description) {
       // Get the current context
       var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
       // Get the web
       var web = context.get_web();
       // Get the Sales list
       var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Sales');
       // create the ListItemInformational object
       var listItemInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
       // add the item to the list
       var listItem = list.addItem(listItemInfo);
       // Assign Values for fields
       listItem.set_item('SalesAchieved', salesachieved);
       listItem.set_item('Customer', customer);
       listItem.set_item('Title', description);
       //Lookup field need to be catered using FieldLookUp value
       var employeeNameValue = new SP.FieldLookupValue();
       employeeNameValue.set_lookupId(employeeId);
       listItem.set_item('EmployeeName', employeeNameValue);
       // Adding value for a Date Field
       var currDate = new Date();
       listItem.set_item('SaleDate', currDate);
       listItem.update();
       //Make a query call to execute the above statements
       context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.on_addSales_Success), Function.createDelegate(this, this.on_addSales_Failure));
    }
    function on_addSales_Success() {
       alert("Sale successfully created.");
    }
    function on_addSales_Failure() {
       alert("Error while creating new Sales.");
    }
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh372944%28v=office.14%29.aspx#odc_spe14_ta_WorkwithJSOM_ManipulatingData

Comment: Hi Hugh, thank you for the answer. My problem here is not to update an item using Javascript, but to launch a new document command and be able to initialize some fields before opening it using Word client. As mentioned in the first post, I did that successfully for some basic fields (Text, Choice etc), but with the lookups field an exception occurs when I try access the value.

Comment: Are you using a SP.FieldLookupValue?

Comment: Yes I tried this and the same error Even for an existing document, Accessing the lookup field value throw the same error.